# How does the browser determine the height of an HTML element

Tags: html, css, dom

Let me start off by saying I am more of a backend developer working on APIs and databases. However, I am currently working on a video chat frontend. I am building it in Angular. My question is about how the browser determines the height of an element. I have a DIV on the page with an id of 'remote_container_tracks'.

I am using an SDK from a company that allows me to generate a video element that contains the tracks of a remote participant.

Once I call the function to generate the HTMLVideoElement, from the SDK, I add the following class to the element,

```
    .remote_video {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        object-fit: cover;
        border-radius: 15px;
    }
```

then I append the element to the remote_tracks_container element.

The following picture shows the DOMRect height of both the container element and the video element before and after appending the video element to the container.

[image]

The top 2 console.log statements show that the height of both is 0 before appending the video element to the container.

Please ignore the fact the height of both elements is written out 3 times each after appending the video element to the container. That is the product of several events being fired that call the same callback function.

After I append the video element to the container, the height of both is 469.75, which makes zero sense to me since they were both zero before I created the parent-child relationship and then after the height jumps to 469.75.

However, that is not the weirdest part. I opened up the console and grabbed a reference to both elements and called the getBoundClientRect() function on both. I am even more confused now to find the height of the container is 702.625 and the height of the video element is 698.625.

Can anyone help me understand what is going on here? I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Your style rule for `.remote-video` contains `object-fit: 100%;`, but 100% is not a valid value for object-fit. Perhaps you want `object-fit: contain;`?

Comment: @BrettDonald - that was just a mistake when I was typing in the question. It is actually set to cover.